# Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using spring boot and spring boot actuator 3.x.x. Now, when a health contributor doesn't exist, an error will be thrown at runtime. Is there a way to disable such error from not getting thrown?

Before, on spring boot and spring boot actuator 2.x.x, no errors were thrown, regardless of whether the application contained the health contributor or not.

Thank you in advance.
Hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on the version you are in, you need to add it as a dependency to activate it? give it a shot:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Also, unlike in previous versions, **Actuator comes with most endpoints disabled.**

So you might have to enable it on your SecurityWebFilterChain, example taken from their documentation:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
      return http.authorizeExchange()
          .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
          .anyExchange().authenticated()
          .and().build();
    }
```